# Convert / Transpose Columns to rows and display only the modified values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, transpose, unpivot

I have a table named "AT_ORDER_INFO" with columns names and values as shown below :-

| ID | OrderNo | OrderType | EngineerName | Comments | Facility | Department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | OD 1 | 5 | Tom | Fitting | C1P1 | Assembly |
| 102 | OD 1 | 5 | Jack | Red | C1P1 | Painting |

I want to display the data changes occurred between 2 records.

Need an SQL Query which will return the below output :-

| Property | OldValue | NewValue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID | 101 | 102 |
| EngineerName | Tom | Jack |
| Comments | Fitting | Red |
| Department | Assembly | Painting |

Requirements :-

1. Output should display only the columns for which there is change in value in both the rows.
   Like in my case (OrderNo,OrderType,Facility) columns have same values in both the rows so dont need this in output. (ID,EngineerName,Comments,Department) have different values so need them in output.
2. Existing Columns names should become the Row Values like we see (ID,EngineerName,Comments,Department).
3. Output Query Should Have 3 Custom Columns names like Property, OldValue, NewValue.

   Property - Contains the Column Names.

   OldValue - Value of corresponding columns value of ID = 101.

   NewValue - Value of corresponding columns value of ID = 102.

Basically, I want to display the data changes occurred between 2 records.

Comment: Why do you think you need to transpose the columns to rows?  The reason I ask is that columns can only have a single data-type, but you're trying to output both integers and strings in the columns `OldValue` and `NewValue`.  That's a code smell, indicating that you're doing something in a way that SQL is not intended to handle.

Comment: @MatBailie Seems like OP is looking for an AUDIT TRAIL,.   I've provided a working option here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f539aa00db4c8a364a3af472bdb34e2a and took a few liberties which may make it more useful like making it dynamic and adding ID's as columns

Answer (score 0):

your data

```
CREATE TABLE AT_ORDER_INFO(
   ID          VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL 
  ,OrderNo      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,OrderType    INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,EngineerName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,Comments     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,Facility     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,Department   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO AT_ORDER_INFO
(ID,OrderNo,OrderType,EngineerName,Comments,Facility,Department) VALUES 
(101,'OD 1',5,'Tom','Fitting','C1P1','Assembly'),
(102,'OD 1',5,'Jack','Red','C1P1','Painting');
```

first you should use `String_agg` WITH `WITHIN GROUP` to ensure the order

```
101 => Old ID
102 => New ID
```

```
select 
string_agg(ID,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) ID,
string_agg(EngineerName,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) EngineerName,
string_agg(Comments,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) Comments,
string_agg(Department,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) Department
from AT_ORDER_INFO
```

| ID | EngineerName | Comments | Department |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101,102 | Tom,Jack | Fitting,Red | Assembly,Painting |

Then you should use this in `Subquery`  and `Unpivot`

```
  select 
  indicatorname as Property,
  indicatorvalue
from (select 
string_agg(ID,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID)  ID,
string_agg(EngineerName,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) EngineerName,
string_agg(Comments,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) Comments,
string_agg(Department,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) Department
from AT_ORDER_INFO) AOI
unpivot
(
  indicatorvalue
  for indicatorname in ([ID]
      ,[EngineerName]
      ,[Comments]
      ,[Department])
) unpiv;
```

| Property | indicatorvalue |
| --- | --- |
| ID | 101,102 |
| EngineerName | Tom,Jack |
| Comments | Fitting,Red |
| Department | Assembly,Painting |

The next step is using methods of splitting column, I have used `Substring`
if values are much more consider `creating a fucntion that split string into columns`, by doing so it is possible to handle Dynamic IDs.

```
select 
indicatorname as  Property,
Substring(indicatorvalue, 1,Charindex(',', indicatorvalue)-1) as 'oldvalue',
Substring(indicatorvalue, Charindex(',', indicatorvalue)+1, LEN(indicatorvalue)) as  'newvalue'
from (select 
string_agg(ID,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID)  ID,
string_agg(EngineerName,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) EngineerName,
string_agg(Comments,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) Comments,
string_agg(Department,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) Department
from AT_ORDER_INFO) m
unpivot
(
  indicatorvalue
  for indicatorname in ([ID]
      ,[EngineerName]
      ,[Comments]
      ,[Department])
) unpiv;
```

| Property | oldvalue | newvalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID | 101 | 102 |
| EngineerName | Tom | Jack |
| Comments | Fitting | Red |
| Department | Assembly | Painting |

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c1a25f1c65daf2f1ca04a23d70bcb2f0)

Comment: Rolling your own array using `STRING_AGG()` then accessing it with `PARSENAME()` fails if any of the values contains a `'.'` - You're better off using `JSON` if you want to go down that route.